# for loop in R to get a table

Tags: r

we are working on our thesis. We want to make a table containing the mean, max, and min of the correlation and rank correlation of one region during different time periods. But the result only gives us the right number for the last time period. The EC1 in the code is the return of different time periods and it's in xts.

```
EC_correlation_table <- matrix(nrow=10,ncol=3,byrow=T)
colnames(EC_correlation_table) <-c("Avg","Max","Min")
rownames(EC_correlation_table) <- rep(c("ρ","ρs"),times=5)
        for (a in c("EC1","EC2","EC3","EC4","EC5") ){
    for (i in seq(1,10,2)) {
      EC_correlation_table[i,1]<-mean(cor(get(a)))
      n <- length(cor(get(a)))
      EC_correlation_table[i,2]<-sort(cor(get(a)))[n-length(colnames(EC))]
      EC_correlation_table[i,3]<-min(cor(get(a)))
      
      EC_correlation_table[i+1,1]<-mean(cor(get(a),method = "spearman"))
       n <- length(cor(get(a),method = "spearman"))
      EC_correlation_table[i+1,2]<-sort(cor(get(a),method = "spearman"))[n-length(colnames(EC))]
      EC_correlation_table[i+1,3]<-min(cor(get(a),method = "spearman"))
    }
    }
```

this is the result we get but apparently, it's just repeating the right number for the last period.

```
 > EC_correlation_table
         Avg       Max       Min
ρ  0.8326252 0.9310787 0.6795128
ρs 0.7920609 0.9139772 0.5997149
ρ  0.8326252 0.9310787 0.6795128
ρs 0.7920609 0.9139772 0.5997149
ρ  0.8326252 0.9310787 0.6795128
ρs 0.7920609 0.9139772 0.5997149
ρ  0.8326252 0.9310787 0.6795128
ρs 0.7920609 0.9139772 0.5997149
ρ  0.8326252 0.9310787 0.6795128
ρs 0.7920609 0.9139772 0.5997149
```

I think we make a tad mistake at some point but just can't figure it out.

Comment: You have nested loops, so in the inner loop, `a` stays the same. You are filling the entire matrix once for EC1, then once for EC2, etc, so the final matrix is just filled with repeating rows of EC5.

Answer (score -1):

after thinking a night, I found the solution~

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  for (a in sort(c("EC1","EC2","EC3","EC4","EC5"))[i] ){
    b<- 1+seq(0,8,2)[i]
  EC_correlation_table[b,1]<-mean(cor(get(a)))
  n <- length(cor(get(a)))
  EC_correlation_table[b,2]<-sort(cor(get(a)))[n-length(colnames(EC))]
  EC_correlation_table[b,3]<-min(cor(get(a)))
  c<- 1+seq(1,9,2)[i]
  EC_correlation_table[c,1]<-mean(cor(get(a),method = "spearman"))
   n <- length(cor(get(a),method = "spearman"))
  EC_correlation_table[c,2]<-sort(cor(get(a),method = "spearman"))[n-length(colnames(EC))]
  EC_correlation_table[c,3]<-min(cor(get(a),method = "spearman"))
}
}
```

Comment: That's... a very roundabout way of doing this.